# Proof with Cauchy-Schwarz

Tags: inequality

Prove that if $x_i > 0$ for all $i$ then
\begin{align*}
&(x_1^{19} + x_2^{19} + \cdots + x_n^{19})(x_1^{93} + x_2^{93} + \cdots + x_n^{93}) \\
&\geq (x_1^{20} + x_2^{20} + \cdots + x_n^{20})(x_1^{92} + x_2^{92} + \cdots + x_n^{92}).
\end{align*}
Also, find when equality holds.
I already know that: \begin{align*}&(x_1^{20} + x_2^{20} + \cdots + x_n^{20})(x_1^{92} + x_2^{92} + \cdots + x_n^{92}) \\ &\geq (x_1^{56} + x_2^{56} + \cdots + x_n^{56})(x_1^{56} + x_2^{56} + \cdots + x_n^{56}),\end{align*}
but I don't know if this is relvant and if so, how to use it.

Comment: you can try induction on $n$.

Comment: Another way: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1018013/difficult-inequalities-question/1018221#1018221

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following chain of CS helps

$$\sum_{i=1}^n x_{i}^{19} \cdot \sum_{i=1}^n x_{i}^{93}\ge \sum_{i=1}^n x_{i}^{20}\cdot \dfrac {\sum_{i=1}^n x_{i}^{20}}{\sum_{i=1}^n x_{i}^{21}}\cdot \sum_{i=1}^n x_{i}^{93}\ge \sum_{i=1}^n x_{i}^{20}\cdot \dfrac {\sum_{i=1}^n x_{i}^{21}}{\sum_{i=1}^n x_{i}^{22}}\cdot \sum_{i=1}^n x_{i}^{93} \ge \\$$

$$\ge \sum_{i=1}^n x_{i}^{20}\cdot \dfrac {\sum_{i=1}^n x_{i}^{22}}{\sum_{i=1}^n x_{i}^{23}}\cdot \sum_{i=1}^n x_{i}^{93}\ge...\ge  \sum_{i=1}^n x_{i}^{20}\cdot \dfrac {\sum_{i=1}^n x_{i}^{92}}{\sum_{i=1}^n x_{i}^{93}}\cdot \sum_{i=1}^n x_{i}^{93}=\sum_{i=1}^n x_{i}^{20} \cdot \sum_{i=1}^n x_{i}^{92}$$

Comment: Could you give a bit more detail as to how that was derived?

Comment: in each step you just use $\dfrac {\sum x_{i}^n} {\sum  x_{i}^{n+1}}\ge \dfrac {\sum x_{i}^{n+1}} {\sum x_{i}^{n+2}} $ which is equivalent to $ \sum x_{i}^n\cdot \sum  x_{i}^{n+2}\ge  (\sum x_{i}^{n+1})^2 $ which is straightforward CS

Comment: I don't see how that is straightforward CS (sorry I'm new to the inequalities)

Comment: $ \sum x_{i}^n\cdot \sum  x_{i}^{n+2}\ge (\sum \sqrt {x_{i}^n \cdot x_{i}^{n+2}})^2=  (\sum x_{i}^{n+1})^2 $

Comment: Ahah!! thanks so much!

Comment: I'm terrible with latex, would you mind copy pasting the latex for that solution in?

Comment: i would help but i dont know how,where should i copy it

Comment: You could just copy paste it without the dollar signs...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27181/discussion-between-bob-the-pie-and-booldy).